# setting the Default Apps doesn't work anymore on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, file-association

Since around a week ago, setting the Default Apps doesn't work anymore. Here's what I do:

MS Windows Explorer -> Click Right-Mouse button on a file (e.g. abc.txt) -> Open with -> Choose another app -> Select "Notepad++" and Check "Always use this app to open *.txt".

After I do the above steps, the default app does NOT change from Notepad to Notepad++.

I tried the following, but they did not work.

1. changing the Windows account from local account to MS account.
2. Settings -> Default Apps -> Choose default applications by file type -> Select ".txt" -> Choose "Notepad++"

Thanks for your effort and time to help...

Comment: It seems to me I have the same problem from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Windows 10 Pro (Version 1803, Build 17134.345) following worked for me:

- Open Notepad++ as an administrator
- Menu > Settings to open the "Preferences" dialog
- Click "File Association"
- Click "Notepad"
- Click ".txt".
- Click "->" to register notepad++ as the program to edit .txt files
- Click "Close"

As a second step do the same you described in your question.